# Ask with asynctask while posting to phpmyadmin

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

Here is my android code for post data to remote db, It doesn't work as I wish, well, it doesn't work at all. No errors, no actions. Help guys. I really don't know what is going on.. Any advice is welcome.

```
    final String suma = Float.valueOf(zam.getSuma()).toString();`

    ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         new MyAsyncTask().execute(suma);
        }
    });

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.msinzynierka.cba.pl/executeConn.php");

        try {
            // Add your data

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_suma",
                    valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my execution php script

[logging & connecting ]
.
.
.
.

```
$Zam_suma = $_POST['Zam_suma'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Zamowienie(Zam_suma) VALUES($Zam_suma)");
```

Comment: Formatting a line as code can be done by adding 4 spaces at its beginning.

Comment: Any hints in the LogCat?

Comment: Put `Log.d()` sentences all along your `AsyncTask` and see the point where it stucks.

Comment: Log.d needs two arguments, which one ?

Comment: LogCat shows nothing.

Comment: @user3293650 The first is the tag, say "phpmyadmin", and the second the text you want to show, for instance, "Hey, I'm in the doInBackground method!". Then you can filter in your logcat by that tag.

Comment: What's this have to do with phpMyAdmin, which is a tool for administrators to manage a database? Perhaps you mean MySQL, which is the database most commonly used with phpMyAdmin. Surely you're not posting data directly to phpMyAdmin in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) the way it is setup is incorrect. I don't know if its your problem or not but you should understand the `params`.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

The first is what is passed to `doInBackground()` during your execution...this looks fine.

The second is what `onProgressUpdate()` takes...this also looks fine since you don't implement that method.

The third is what is passed to `onPostExecute()` from the `return` in `doInBackground()`...this doesn't look fine. You are telling onPostExecute()`to expect nothing and returning nothing in`doInBackground()`which would be correct but then your`onPostExecute()` should look like

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

Since your method signature is incorrect, you aren't actually overriding the `AsyncTask` method but it thinks that it is your own method and won't run when `doInBackground()` has finished. This is where the `@Override` annotation comes in handy.

Comment: I've changed that declaration but nothing has changed.

Comment: Wait! First errors! :D
02-10 21:22:26.624: W/System.err(23590): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /95.211.144.89 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)